# How do i edit the source list in microsoft excel data validation

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I created a spreadsheet a few months ago and have a drop down list where i typed in a formula to populate the list from a range in another sheet. Now i have added more items to the range on the other sheet but i cannot edit the source for the drop down list to include it.

When i open the data validation box and click on the source box to edit it, nothing happens. I can highlight the contents but i cannot delete or add any characters for some reason.

This is the existing formula:

```
=IFS(B2=1,SectionProperties!B4:B18,B2=2,SectionProperties!B19:**B141**,B2=3,SectionProperties!B144:B165,B2=4,SectionProperties!B166:B285,B2=5,SectionProperties!B286:B298,B2=6,SectionProperties!B299:B310,B2=7,SectionProperties!B324:B352,B2=8,SectionProperties!B397:B505,B2=9,SectionProperties!B506:B519,B2=10,SectionProperties!B520:B550,B2=11,SectionProperties!B552:B683,B2=12,SectionProperties!B684:B709)
```

and this is what i need to change it to:

```
=IFS(B2=1,SectionProperties!B4:B18,B2=2,SectionProperties!B19:**B143**,B2=3,SectionProperties!B144:B165,B2=4,SectionProperties!B166:B285,B2=5,SectionProperties!B286:B298,B2=6,SectionProperties!B299:B310,B2=7,SectionProperties!B324:B352,B2=8,SectionProperties!B397:B505,B2=9,SectionProperties!B506:B519,B2=10,SectionProperties!B520:B550,B2=11,SectionProperties!B552:B683,B2=12,SectionProperties!B684:B709)
```

I know its probably a terrible way to write the formula, but it works. Please kindly do not rip me apart for bad formulas, though suggestions for improvement would be much appreciated. I just need to change one little number and cant figure out how.

Thanks for your help.

[Sample file with problem](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AV6-SSxrWrrGufBmGQ_SscT2tCqg3DCn/view?usp=sharing)

Select Cell A4, go to data validation. Unable to edit source line.

Comment: This is looking wrong `**B143**` ,, otherwise rest part is okay,, better [Edit] your post & add link of the file to examine !!

Comment: Please provide a sample about your problem, we need more clearly information.

Comment: @Rajesh S I typed it as normal text, the **B143** would have appeared bold in the post to direct your attention to what I am trying to edit, but someone took it upon themself to edit my post and put the code in code block with no regard to my purpose for not putting it in a code block, making the question confusing.

Comment: @Lee There really isn't any sample I can post short of posting my actual Excel file. I will have to remove some confidential info before I can upload though.